# Using Half Pipe assets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use Half Pipe gem [half-pipe (0.3.0.beta.2)] with Rails 4.0.0 but keep on getting

> Warning: RequireJS failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

First, I thought it's a problem with my node installation, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this error was a path issue while requirejs is looking for query. It has already been [fixed](https://github.com/d-i/half-pipe/commit/3d434b37bd3076445782c8c8dc40cde78511c1e7) in the halfpipe codebase. Updating my Gemfile to pull the latest half pipe code from github sorted it:

Gemfile

```
gem 'half-pipe', :github => "d-i/half-pipe"
```

Other than that, have you got the latest levels of npm, node, bower and grunt installed? I had to update each of these to get my install working.

I have: npm (1.4.7), grunt-cli v0.1.13, grunt v0.4.4, bower 1.3.2 and node v0.9.9 running on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Indeed. It solved the problem also with my configuration: npm 1.4.3, grunt-cli 0.1.13, grunt 0.4.4, bower 1.3.2, node 0.10.26.